# searching through sql field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to search in sql field which is not a part ofjoined but an external table which has some relevance with the ID of the one of the joined tables.

here is my query where i am trying some search

```
SELECT sdate,stime (select catid from 
users where id = OM.id) as catid
FROM 
table2 AS OM 
INNER JOIN table2 a ON a.pid = OM.pid 
where 1=1 
AND (select catid from 
users where id = OM.id) = '120'
```

this is where i am getting an error

**AND (select catid from 
    users where id = OM.id) = '120'**

```
[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.
42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

Comment: You will need to join the users table to the OM table first before you can make a query.

Comment: Can you please give us the structure of the tables and some example data. It is much easier to answer your question when we work with correct data.

Comment: the structure of data is that two `table1` and `table 2` can be joined by their own `PID`, while the one ID field is only `existant` in the users table

Comment: You need to provide some actual details here about what you are trying to do. We also need to see some table details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a comma after stime?

Change

```
SELECT sdate, stime (select catid from 
users where id = OM.id) as catid
FROM ...
```

to

```
SELECT sdate, stime, (select catid from 
users where id = OM.id) as catid
FROM ...
```

Comment: that was a miss, i added but that does not the issue i have

Comment: I am still at a loos trying to understand why you do not want to use `inner join`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical flaw here. You might receive more than 1 row in your subquery. Why don't you just join to users instead of this strange subquery?

```
SELECT sdate
    , stime
    , u.catid
FROM 
table2 AS OM 
INNER JOIN table2 a ON a.pid = OM.pid 
inner join user u on u.id = OM.id
where u.catid = '120'
```

Comment: the select statement which is in brackets, it will give me only 1 record because id match, that thing i need in where clause, but if join, it gives me results for empty id's too which is wrong

Comment: How can it give you results where ID is empty??? It can only return rows where the value of ID is 120. Perhaps you have simplified your query so much for posting that you have hidden the real issue. Logically comparing a subquery to a scalar value doesn't make any sense because the subquery CAN return more than 1 row. You know that it won't based on the data but the parser doesn't